# After changing the port number, connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Tags: postgresql, port

1. I finished install postgresql11 and to change port number
2. The first file I modified was '/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf'

> #listen_addresses = 'localhost' -> listen_addresses ='*'

> ```
> #port = 5432 -> port = 9485
> ```

3. The second file I modified was '/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf'

the line i added is 'host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5'

```html
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

4. i restarted postgresql server

> systemctl restart postgresql-11

5. Connection from external client to dbeaver works fine.
6. but local connection is not fine

> su - postgres

> psql

there is error message

> psql: could not connect to server: There is no such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

7. I can find two files in '/var/run/postgresql'

> .s.PGSQL.9485

> .s.PGSQL.9485.lock

8. If Ireturn the port to the original number of 5432, it works normally again.
9. Please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete your setup you have to change environment variable PGPORT

```
PGPORT=9495; export PGPORT;
```

If not you have to give port number ( -p 9495 ) to every cde (psql, pg_dump, ...)

Answer (score 4):

`psql` is not aware of your Postgres settings, it is using the default port `5432`.

Try: `psql -p 9485`